# jQuery multi level navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

Hello i have created a multi level navigation in magento. Now i have a problem with the opening and closing of my menu. I want my menu to close the "active" Top Menu when the other Top Menu is clicked.
I cant seem to get this part correct.

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {    
        jQuery(".sub_category").hide();
        jQuery(".sub_sub_category").hide();

        jQuery('#product-nav li a').click(function () {
            jQuery('#product-nav li a').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        });

        jQuery('ul li.expanded a').each(function(i){
            var subUl = jQuery(this).parent().find('ul'); //Get the sub ul.
            jQuery(this).bind('click',function(e){
                     // Prevent the default action of the link
                    subUl.toggle();
                }) ;   
        });
        jQuery(".head_child").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
        });
        jQuery('li:has(ul) > a').click(function(e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
        });

            var url = window.location.toString();

        jQuery('ul li.expanded a').each(function(){         
            var myHref= jQuery(this).attr('href');
            var subUl = jQuery(this).parent().find('ul'); //Get the sub ul.
            if( url.match(myHref)) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('activeElement')
                subUl.toggle();
        }
});       
});
```

Please see my jsfiddle for the example of my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/wvEcF/1/

Comment: I tried to fiure out what your plan is, but are not sure right now. Maybe you could try to explain it a bit more? Just from the jsfiddle: It's not a good idea to use the same id for an element twice.

Comment: Indeed a good point about the id's. But what i want to archive is that, when Top menu Item is open and Top menu Item 2 is clicked. That Top menu Item will automatically close.

Comment: You must really like typing jQuery.